# Single boot fakeRAID-0 UEFI GPT problem with a strange workaround

Tags: system-installation, uefi, raid, gpt, fakeraid

I wanted to install a single boot Ubuntu 20.10 on fakeRAID-0 UEFI GPT by a live bootable flash disk. The system did not boot after installation, so I checked whether Ubiquity correctly installed UEFI and GRUB on the boot partition, and it verified OK.

I have found a **magic workaround** for my problem, I booted by a windows 8.1 DVD but did not let it to do any changes to my system and I shutdown just when the very first installation window appeared. Then I detached the DVD drive. Restarted the system and Ubuntu boots nicely.

Another observation I have is, whenever I want to use GParted in Ubuntu it complains as:

[image]

and I should hit <kbd>Ignore</kbd>. Otherwise if I hit <kbd>Fix</kbd>, the error will disappear but system will not boot next time. However if I redo the **magic workaround** again, everything goes well and the GParted error comes back. And I mention again that I do not need Ubuntu bootable flash at all. Also it worth mentioning I have used this **magic workaround** successfully from Ubuntu 14.04 till now.

My question is that what magic is done by windows DVD and how can I mimic the process within OS itself or live Ubuntu so that I get rid of windows DVD?

Comment: I would run this summary report which shows details of boot config, before & after and see what difference there is:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair I would not trust Windows on anything related to Linux. What does `sudo gdisk -l /dev/xxxx for your device. You know RAID 0 is not normally recommended. "Don't bother with RAID 0 unless you have a specific need for speed without data redundancy, since if one drive goes out, you lose the whole array." https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444499

Comment: As I mentioned windows does not do any change to system. It seems it only move some blocks of disk. Also I need to use RAID0 to have a single disk, otherwise I have two 128GB disks with deep poor performance. On my system RAID0 boots almost 15 times faster than dual disk.

Comment: I already read and tried whatever discussed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto with no results.

Comment: @muru Do you know the difference between fakeraid vs raid? And do you know it has nothing with system-installation at all?

Comment: You're asking about a problem you had immediately after installing a system. That has everything to do with [tag:system-installation]

Comment: OK @muru but please do not remove fakeraid tag. If my system was a raid one, this problem would not occur. So the root cause of this problem is fakeraid.

Comment: In that case, please remember to add a tag wiki and excerpt for the new tag you created at https://askubuntu.com/tags/fakeraid/info

Comment: I have a question, I'm here to ask it. So contributing to AskUbuntu is not my goal now. @muru you can always do the tag wiki thing if you want. The resource for difference between raid and fakeraid is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto

Comment: Yet you're oddly insistent in contributing to tags without meaning. You could have spent the time writing that useless response in simply editing the wiki and excerpt for something you insist on having.

Comment: I already added the tag wiki and it's waiting for confirmation. By the way it's not a good way to call other community members contributions as USELESS. @muru if you have answer to my question please write it, otherwise please kindly leave it to others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115832/discussion-between-shvahabi-and-muru).